# Can I trust the result of a one-way ANOVA with many treatments each with very few replicates

Tags: anova, statistical-significance, statistical-power

I am doing a one-way ANOVA of a response variable (Y) on a treatment factor (T) of 7 levels. However, for each treatment, I have only 2 observations (or replicates). The ANOVA result shows the the means across the treatment are highly significant (p<0.001). I have check the normal and constant-variance assumptions and seems that my data does not violate these assumptions.

My question is: Can I trust the result of ANOVA, even if the sample size is extremely small (n=2*7=14)?

The first question that comes to my mind is the power of my test. Since  my ANOVA has obtained an effect size of 0.9. I conducted a power analysis (using Q*Power.3) to see how many samples are needed to obtain such effect size with significance level of 0.05 and power of 0.8. The result showed that I need at least 28 samples. Since I have much fewer samples than required, does it mean that my ANOVA results are not reliable?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by 'trust'. If the assumptions hold, the chance of a type I error is just your significance level - it's not a function of sample size (*power* sure is - but that's not an issue for you). Your power analysis shows that you don't have a high power ... but nevertheless you did reject. Small sample size doesn't increase the chance that you'll wrongly reject - on average it decreases it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by 'trust'. If the assumptions hold, the chance of a type I error is just your significance level - it's not a function of sample size (power sure is - but that's not an issue for you). Your power analysis shows that you don't have a high power ... but nevertheless you did reject. Small sample size doesn't increase the chance that you'll wrongly reject - on average it decreases it.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @Glen_b as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.